# Use nil instead of Optional(<null>) for null value in JSON

Tags: json, swift

In Swift, `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` uses `Optional(<null>)` for `null` value in JSON. Is that possible to tell the parse to use `nil` instead (i.e., drop fields with `null` values because Swift `Dictionary` doesn't allow `nil` value)?

Comment: BTW, what is `Optional(<null>)` actually? What's the type of the value being wrapped in the optional?

Comment: I don't think it's giving you a `Dictionary` object, it's giving you an `NSDictionary` isn't it? Since they can't store `nil`, what you're asking can't be done.

Comment: Yes, Swift briges `NSDictionary` to `[NSObject: AnyObject]`. Since `Dictonary` cannot store `nil`, they use `NSNull`

Comment: `Dictionary` can store `nil`, I just tested it. `NSDictionary` cannot however and regardless of any bridging you must work with the limitations of the actual object (an NSDictionary) and not what it's being bridged to. If you want a real `Dictionary` iterate through the `NSDictionary` and create one, converting `NSNull` to `null`. This will be extremely slow however.

Comment: `Dictionary` cannot store `nil`. When you assign `nil` to a field, you  **delete** that field effectively. `var a = ["x": 1, "y": 2]; a["x"] = nil; println(a.count)` prints `1`. I use xcode6-beta5.

Comment: @Ethan: Not true. Dictionaries can store `nil` if the value type of the dictionary is an optional type: `var a: [String: Int?] = ["x": 1, "y": 2]; a["x"] = (nil as Int?); println(a.count)` prints `2`. (Note that I don't do `a["x"] = nil` because the subscript operator takes an optional of the value type, in this case `Int??`. If it is `nil`, that means remove the key; if it is non-`nil` it stores it. But if you just write `nil`, it will be interpreted as `nil` of `Int??`. `(nil as Int?)` forces it to be converted to non-`nil` `Int??` containing `nil` `Int?`.)

Comment: But the dictionary type you get from NSJSONSerialization are `NSDictionary` (or `[String: AnyObject]`), which can't store `nil`.

Comment: @Ethan `NSDictionary` instances can't store `nil`, but they can return `nil` if the requested key does not exist. For this reason, it seems like Swift should bridge `NSDictionary` to `[String: AnyObject?]` rather than `[String: AnyObject]`. I'm not sure why Apple decided to use a non-optional value type here.

Comment: I just looked at the docs for the Swift `Dictionary` class. The `subscript(key:)` method returns an optional type. So that explains how missing values are handled in Swift.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

NSJSONSerialization uses `NSNull` objects, and that's what you're seeing; you can simply check for them by comparing to `NSNull()`.

Comment: That's ugly. I have a big json object whose values could be a string or null. So instead of casting the whole thing to `[String : String]`, I'll have to use `[String : AnyObject]` and everytime I need to access a field I have to write something like `value = (dict["field1"] == nil || dict["field1"] is NSNull) ? nil : (dict["field1"]! as String)` instead of just `value = dict["field1"]`

Comment: @Ethan I'm not sure if you are asking a separate question here, but there is no good way to include `nil` without wrapping everything in Optional; especially since NSJSONSerialization is an Obj-C class, it has no Optional, and must use NSNull. If you want to filter NSNulls out of a dictionary, you can write a simple extension or global function to do so.

Comment: @Ethan When parsing, it is never safe to cast to `[String: String]` if you know there can be `nil` values. It's better to parse the fields separately into your custom struct/class when the attributes can be accessed as properties not as string keys. Also, the simple type-safe pattern is `value = dict["field1"] as? String`, you don't have to check specifically for `NSNull`. Check for the type you want to have.

Answer (score 18):

Optional() is an `NSNull` value. You can avoid error like this:

```
if !(myField is NSNull) {
    //Whatever you want to do with myField when not null
} else {
    //Whatever you want to do when myField is null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is a problem with your JSON schema. null and string are different types of things in JSON. The fact that your key can have a value that is sometimes null and sometimes a string seems to me that you guys are not following a rigorous schema.

A good design would have the key either not be there, or if it is there, its value is guaranteed to be a string. Accessing the dictionary key in Swift produces an optional, which is `nil` if the key is not there, or a value if the key is there (in which case you know it's a string), which matches what you want.

Comment: This is incorrect. Null represents the absence of a value. Omitting the value simply means the same thing.

Comment: @GregBrown: No it isn't. Null is a type of value in JSON.

Comment: Null is a possible *value* in JSON. It isn't a type. By definition, the null value has no type. By your logic, a JSON document should define a key whose value is either null or isn't present. There's no practical use case for that.

Comment: @GregBrown: Regardless of your personal philosophy of using null, the point is, the JSON specification treats a key whose value as null very differently than a key that isn't there, and all JSON implementation libraries likewise treat them differently. They do not "simply mean the same thing".

Comment: The JSON specification says nothing about how null should be handled. It simply defines it as one of the valid values. But either way, your suggestion still doesn't make any sense. Of course it is valid to define a "schema" that includes values that may or may not be present! Otherwise, we wouldn't have nullable columns in SQL or optional types in Swift, for example. For all practical purposes, the absence of an optional value is universally represented by null.