# How to convert NSNull to nil in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I want to fetch JSON data from my server and manipulate it upon launch. In Objective-C, I have used this `#define` code to convert `NSNull` to `nil`, since the fetched data might include null at times.

```
#define NULL_TO_NIL(obj) ({ __typeof__ (obj) __obj = (obj); __obj == [NSNull null] ? nil : obj; })
```

However, in Swift, is it possible to convert the `NSNull` to `nil`? I want to use the following operation (the code is Objective-C's):

```
people.age = NULL_TO_NIL(peopleDict["age"]);
```

In the above code, when the fetched data's `age` key is `NULL`, then the `people` object's `.age` property is set to `nil`.

I use Xcode 6 Beta 6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use nil instead of Optional(<null>) for null value in JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321261/use-nil-instead-of-optionalnull-for-null-value-in-json)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This could be what you are looking for:

```
func nullToNil(value : Any?) -> Any? {
    if value is NSNull {
        return nil
    } else {
        return value
    }
}

people.age = nullToNil(peopleDict["age"])
```

Comment: suppose this is a good way for string literal . i have updated the code for zero references as well

Answer (score 14):

I would recommend, instead of using a custom conversion function, just to cast the value using `as?`:

```
people.age = peopleDict["age"] as? Int
```

If the value is `NSNull`, the `as?` cast will fail and return `nil`.