# AnyObject is not convertible to 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, casting, compiler-errors

I am getting the following error AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String'. I am getting this error on the line `if (answerArray != NSNull()  && answerArray != nil)`

I try casting it as String, but it didn't fix the problem. I posted the whole code below.

```
 let answerArray : AnyObject = jsonparser.objectWithString(answer)
 if (answerArray != NSNull()  && answerArray != nil) {

}
```

Comment: What's the return type of `objectWithString`?

Comment: An NSArray is the return type.

Comment: In that case, the `if` statement is unnecessary - if that returns a `NSArray`, just assign it to a variable of the same type: `let answerArray: NSArray = jsonparser.objectWithString(answer)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that `jsonparser.objectWithString(answer)` is supposed to return an array, basing on the name of the variable it is assigned to.

If it's an array of heterogeneous types, you can attempt a cast to `NSArray`:

```
if let answerArray = jsonparser.objectWithString(answer) as? NSArray {
    ...
}
```

If the array is supposed to contain objects of the same type (let's say `Int`) instead, then you can try a cast to a swift array:

```
if let answerArray = jsonparser.objectWithString(answer) as? [Int] {
    ...
}
```

Note that a non-optional variable can **never** be `nil` - and you have declared `answerArray` as a non-optional.

If you want to check for `NSNull`, I suggest reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25575030/148357) and related answer.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the error is with `answerArray != nil` - Swift is silly in that the error it returns here is "not convertible to String". More helpful would be `answerArray` is not Optional.

And that's your problem - you have `let answerArray : AnyObject...` - and `AnyObject` is not `Optional`. In Swift, 'answerArray' is never 'nil', because only `Optional` types can be `nil`.

Without looking at what `jsonparser.objectWithString` does, it's hard for me to correct your code, but in essence, the compiler is telling you that you are checking a non-optional type for nil - which is incorrect.