# Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' to 'NSNumber'

Tags: ios, mysql, json, swift

I have a iOS application that interfaces with an API to get data.
Until now everything was working fine. However, it seems that the app is crashing after login. Here is my code:

```
func Evaluate(response:NSDictionary)
{
    ClientWorkoutID = response["clientworkout_id"] as! Int
    ProgramUserID = response["clientworkout_userid"] as! Int
    ProgramID = response["clientworkout_programid"] as! Int
    WorkoutID = response["clientworkout_workoutid"] as! Int
    WorkoutWeek = response["clientworkout_week"] as! Int
    WorkoutDay = response["clientworkout_day"] as! Int
    DayType = response["clientworkout_daytype"] as! Int
    ExType = response["clientworkout_extype"] as! Int
    MuscleGroup = response["clientworkout_musclegroup"] as! Int
    ExName = response["clientworkout_exname"] as? String ?? ""

    ExID = response["clientworkout_exid"] as! Int

    Order = 7 * (WorkoutWeek - 1) + WorkoutDay
    SetCount = response["clientworkout_sets"] as! Int
    Sets = response["clientworkout_setcontent"] as? String ?? ""
    SetInfo = response["clientworkout_setinfo"] as? String ?? ""
    ExerciseProgress = response["clientworkout_exprogress"] as! Double
    DayProgress = response["clientworkout_dayprogress"] as! Double
}
```

The error is in the line 129:

[image]

I've tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575030/how-to-convert-nsnull-to-nil-in-swift).
I've also checked in phpmyadmin/MySQL database, but I don't see anything that could be causing the problem.

[image]

Comment: That simply means that the value of "clientworkout_exid" in the JSON is **null** and not a number ... Note that each of your forced casts can crash if the server does not exactly send what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

use if let or guard statement to check. As an example:

```
if let link = dict["somethingToCheck"] as? String 
{ 
    //if code execute
} 
else {
    //else code execute
}
```